# PowerShell code to check the exported filename first before Export-Mailbox as .PST doesn't work

Tags: powershell, scripting, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to fix the PowerShell code below:

Input file is First Last name in a .TXT format (one column), which then I was able to convert them into the proper Output.CSV file like:

```
"WindowsEmailAddress"
"Russel.Peters@domain.com"
"Amalia.Zebech@domain.com"
"Henry.Ho@domain.com"
"Bing.Fang@domain.com"
"Karina.Michaels@domain.com"
```

This is the code:

```
$Server = 'PRDFILESVR01-VM'
$ServerBackupUNCPath = "\\$Server\PST"
$InputCSVPath = 'C:\LOGS\Input.csv'
$ExportCSVPath = 'C:\LOGS\Output.csv'
$ExportExistsCSVPath = 'C:\LOGS\Exists.csv'

Import-PSSession ($Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://PRDEXC03-VM/Powershell/ -Authentication Kerberos)

$Users = Get-Content -Path $InputCSVPath
&{
    foreach ($User in $Users) {
        Write-Host "Processing.... $User"
        Get-Mailbox $User.ToString() | Select WindowsEmailAddress 
    } 
} | Export-Csv -Path $ExportCSVPath -NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv -Path $ExportCSVPath |
  Get-MailBox | 
  % {
    Write-Host "Processing .... $($_.Name) ..." -ForegroundColor Green

    # Check if the file already exist or not
    $FileResult = Test-Path -Path "$ServerBackupUNCPath\$($_.WindowsEmailAddress).PST" -PathType Leaf

    if ( $FileResult -ne $True ) {
        #If there is no exported .PST file on the destination folder, then begin the export mailbox command and log if there any error to the AliasName.LOG file:
        New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $_ -FilePath "$ServerBackupUNCPath\$($_.WindowsEmailAddress).PST" -BadItemLimit 50 -AcceptLargeDataLoss -WhatIf
        # wait until error or processed:
        while ( ($req = Get-MailboxExportRequest $_) | ? { $_.Status -match 'Queued|InProgress' } )
        { Start-Sleep 180 } 
        $req | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics -IncludeReport | Select -Expand Report | Out-File "C:\LOGS\$($_.WindowsEmailAddress).log"
    } else {
        Write-Output "The user $($_.WindowsEmailAddress).PST file is already existing"
        #Append the list of already existing list of users C:\LOGS\Exist.csv
        ($_.Alias) | Out-File -FilePath $ExportExistsCSVPath -Append
    }

    # I assume, whetever line I put here will be executed regardless of any of the condition above is met or not
    Write-Host "Removing Mailbox $($_.WindowsEmailAddress)" -ForegroundColor Red
    Remove-Mailbox -Identity $_ -Confirm $false -WhatIf

  }
```

However, there is something not right hence the `Get-Mailbox` is seems to be the cause of this issue as the below error shows:

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object '"WindowsEmailAddress"' couldn't be found on 'PRDDC01-VM-VM.domain.com'.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=PRDEXC03-VM,RequestId=c061c8a3-72b6-469a-8109-726e1b015441,TimeStamp=21/08/2018 12:12:13 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] ED9B9A7,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailbox
+ PSComputerName        : PRDEXC03-VM

The operation couldn't be performed because object '"Russel.Peters@domain.com"' couldn't be found on 'PRDDC01-VM-VM.domain.com'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=PRDEXC03-VM,RequestId=c061c8a3-72b6-469a-8109-726e1b015441,TimeStamp=21/08/2018 12:12:13 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] FE47387B,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailbox
    + PSComputerName        : PRDEXC03-VM

The operation couldn't be performed because object '"Amalia.Zebech@domain.com"' couldn't be found on 'PRDDC01-VM-VM.domain.com'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=PRDEXC03-VM,RequestId=c061c8a3-72b6-469a-8109-726e1b015441,TimeStamp=21/08/2018 12:12:13 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] 3DFB1CD9,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailbox
    + PSComputerName        : PRDEXC03-VM

The operation couldn't be performed because object '"Karina.Michaels@domain.com"' couldn't be found on 'PRDDC01-VM-VM.domain.com'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=PRDEXC03-VM,RequestId=c061c8a3-72b6-469a-8109-726e1b015441,TimeStamp=21/08/2018 12:12:13 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] 3DFB1CD9,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailbox
    + PSComputerName        : PRDEXC03-VM
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Get-Mailbox returns `WindowsEmailAddress` in your first get - ie `Get-Mailbox $User.ToString() | Select WindowsEmailAddress`

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.exchange.data.directory.management.mailbox_members.aspx

Comment: As for this..."I don't think Get-Mailbox returns WindowsEmailAddress", yes, yes it does, but not in the default dataset, you have to ask for it or all to get it. Example: ((Get-Mailbox -Filter * | Select *)[0]) -match 'WindowsEmailAddress'
 and the return result is - True